# Databases not listing in Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I have an account on CPANEL and I want to create a database on mysql but it doesn't appear on the list

You can see in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL feature has been disabled by your hosting provider. Please contact them to enable this for your account.